# Show that for any prime $p$ and any integer $m$, $m^p + (p − 1)! m$ is divisible by $p$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm currently working on the following exercise:

> Show that for every prime number $p$ and every integer $m$, the number
>   $m^p + (p − 1)! m$ is divisible by $p$.

What I'm doing is the following:

$$m(m^{p-1}+(p-1)!)\equiv 0\mod p$$
$$m((1)+(-1))\equiv 0\mod p$$
$$m(0)\equiv 0 \mod p$$
$$0 \equiv 0 \mod p.$$

Is a valid proof? Am I missing something? Any hint or help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I think you basically have the idea, but the last line of your proof should be what you want to prove, viz., $m^p+(p-1)!m \equiv 0 \pmod p$, rather than the tautology $0 \equiv 0 \pmod p$

Comment: Also it would be good to state justification or reference for $m^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Show that for every prime number $p$ and every integer $m$, the number
>   $mp+(p−1)!m$ is divisible by $p$.

This can be proved via two theorems:  Fermat's Little Theorem and Wilson's Theorem.

$\,m^p+(p-1)!m \;=\; m^p-m+(p-1)!m+m \;=\; m^p-m+m((p-1)!+1)$

By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $\,m^p-m\,$ is an integer multiple of $p$, since $p$ is prime.

By [Wilson's Theorem](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/Wilsons.html), $\, (p-1)!+1\,$ is an integer multiple of $\,p\,$, since $\,p\,$ is prime.

So, for some $\, k,\,l \in \mathbb{Z}\text{,}\,$ we have
$$m^p-m+m((p-1)!+1) \;=\; kp + m(lp) \;=\; p(k+ml)\text{.}$$

Thus $\,m^p+(p−1)!m\,$ is divisible by $p$.

---

I believe the error in your proof came from assuming that $\,m^{p-1}\equiv1\,(\text{mod}\; p)\text{.}\,$ This is only true if we assume $m$ is not divisible by $p$.

Comment: If you don't assume $p\not \mid m$, then the original expression is divisible by $p$ on its face. So the assumption $p\not \mid m$ is necessary to render the problem nontrivial. Even so, you are correct that the assumption should be explicitly stated, and the trivial case identified  as such.

Comment: @KeithBackman  Thank you for clarifying this; excellent point.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be a prime number and $m$ an integer.

By Fermat's little theorem, $m^p \equiv m \pmod p$, and by Wilson's theorem $(p-1)! 
\equiv -1 \pmod p$.

Therefore, $ m^p + (p-1)!m \equiv m+(-1) \times m \equiv m-m \equiv 0 \pmod p$,

so $p$ divides $m^p+(p-1)!m.$

Comment: To use Fermat's little theorem in this context, we must assume that $m$ is not divisible by $p$.  It's much stronger to use $m^p \equiv m \, (mod\, p)$, that way we don't have to constrict $m$.

Comment: Point well taken.  I edited accordingly.